# Why Firefox is consuming Internet and almost 70% CPU and how to stop this behavior?

Tags: windows-10, firefox

This has really frustrated me. First, CPU and Power Usage is too high, as compared to Edge browser. And in my Nework tab, it also keeps sending and receiving data (every 5-10 seconds) even when browser is not open. Even when I don't start Firefox, these things keep running. I tried to find solutions online, tried them and nothing worked.

[image]

I set `false` to following two things:

`toolkit.winRegisterApplicationRestart`
`browser.tabs.remote.autostart`

And uncheked *Use a background service to install updates* in Firefox settings. Still nothing solved.

As soon as I restart system, these background *culprits* return.

How do I fix it without uninstalling Firefox?

**Process Explorer:**

[image]

**Command Line** Data (Found it using Process Explorer) for 2 of all Firefox processes:

`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -no-remote -headless -new-instance -P "user" --start-debugger-server ws:6000 http://www.google.com.857676347096761.windows-display-service.com`

`"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -contentproc --channel="3416.0.1247913019\656572348" -childID 1 -isForBrowser -prefsHandle 2424 -prefMapHandle 2416 -prefsLen 1 -prefMapSize 238877 -parentBuildID 20210504152106 -appdir "C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser" - 3416 "\\.\pipe\gecko-crash-server-pipe.3416" 2496 tab`

**TCP View:**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124284/discussion-on-question-by-vikas-why-firefox-is-consuming-internet-and-almost-70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem has been solved, I'm writing answer which is based on conversation in comments of the original question. That helped me fix problem.

---

Actually it was because of a few crypto-currency mining malwares. One of the malwares had a name something like *Bitcoin mining*.

Another malware had name: `Microsoft Update Services.vbe` which is also a crypto-currency mining infection.

I installed trial version of MalwareBytes and removed all malwares except 2 DLL files, because those were necessary for Windows OS. (Removing DLLs gave me error whenever Windows would start. Strange though)

Once done, I deleted are quarantined files and restarted PC and problem was fixed.